# unslider not working when using another jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented two different jquery scripts for a website. One is for "unslider" to view sliding photos in the `banner div` and the other is a hovering underline called magicline.js for the `menu div`. The problem is unslider stops working when I want to use magicline.js for the `menu div`. It looks like these two scripts are in conflict with each other. I can't figure out what is happening between these two scripts. Let me know if you have an idea

You can view the website that I am working on at bravodesignbc.com

Here is the html for the site:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/unsliderNew.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/magicLine.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});

$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 400,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: false,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false            //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
});
</script>






</head>

<body>

<!---

--->

<div id="header">
    <div id="headerWrap">
        <div id="brand">  

            <img style="position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 0px;" src="images/bdLogo.png" />

            <h1>Bravo Design</h1>
            <h3>Renovation & Construction</h3>

        </div>
        <p id=rightHead> contact us <br /> 604.723.6059</p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="menuWrap">
        <ul class="group" id="menu">
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>  
</div>



<div id="feature">

    <div class="banner">

        <div class="buttonPrev">
         <a href="#"  class="unslider-arrow prev"><img src="images/prev.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonNext">
         <a href="#"  class="unslider-arrow next"><img src="images/next.png" /></a>
        </div> 

        <div class="bottomBanner">
        <h2>Serving the lower mainland<br />
        for over twenty years
        </h2>
        </div>


         <script>
        var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

        $('.unslider-arrow').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
              unslider.data('unslider')['next']();  
            } else {
              unslider.data('unslider')['prev']();  
            };
        });
        </script>


        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/knappen.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/closeupChandelier.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="listBg"><h3>Slide 3</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>



<div id="content">
     <div id="contentWrap">
        <div id="desc"><p>Bravo Design was created by its founder Waldemar Slonina. Waldemar is pronounced “Valdemar” in Polish.  Waldemar started Bravo Design unofficially in 1992 when he arrived in Vancouver from Europe.  He originally worked for another larger company, at first, but did side jobs, where he first got a taste of owning a business.  Then, he began with a small framing business, which quickly led to more work in renovations and construction around Vancouver.  Soon, he started to gain business all around the Lower Mainland.  Since, he has worked locally in the Tri-cities and Vancouver.<br /><br />

    His former clients would classify him as reliable, on-budget, hard working, on-schedule, and diligent.  These qualities have helped him sustain a successful small business for over two decades.  He approaches each new project with enthusiasm!<p>
        </div>

        <div id="column">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">Testimonials</h3>
        <p style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 0px;">"The job you did with our kitchen is amazing yayayayyayayda" <br />
    <i>-Art Vandelay,</i> Maple Ridge</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerWrap">

      <div id="leftFoot"><img style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px;" src="images/logoMini.png" />
        <p style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" > Bravo Design</p>
        <p style="position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 40px; font-size: 11px; border-top:solid 1px #FFF;" > Renovation & Construction</p>
          </div>

          <div id="rightFoot"><p style="font-size: 12px;">Copyright 2013. Bravo Design. All rights reserved.<br />
            Website design by <a href="http://www.thinkchameleon.com" style="color: #F00; text-decoration:none">think Chameleon</a></p></div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to check the conflict in console (firebug) and let us know.

Comment: The only bug it found was 

TypeError: `ul.queue(...)` is undefined in line 155 of `unsliderNew.js`
 
The following string contains the bug:
`if (!ul.queue('fx').length) {`

Comment: I solved my own problem. It was simpler than I thought. I went to the `magicline.js` script and deleted some code that was manipulating css/html that never existed. I was meaning to delete that part of the script before but did not get around to it till now.